# Is it possible to set a sign-up quota per minute?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a project where users can sign in anonymously. But, I don't want malicious users to spam the login button. I only see an option in the Firebase console to set an hourly sign-up quota, but I need a per minute or per second quota to solve my issue. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the console is your only option.  Otherwise, your project is limited by what you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits).  Note that it doesn't cost you anything for Firebase to process a new anonymous signin.  If you want, you can write backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK to [list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) unused or suspicious accounts.

If you have a feature request, you can send those to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Ok, thanks! In my project, after a user signs into my website, I add them to a room with other users. If someone spams the login button, it creates a bunch of new users and adds them all to a room. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Write code in your client app to debounce the button clicks.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I'll look into that. Do you know if there is a way to do this on the server side?

Comment: The configuration setting you're looking at **is** the server side.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Couldn't a malicious user delete the code that sets the debounce? Forgive me--I'm rather new to this!

Comment: Yes, they could.  The only control you have on the server side is that one configuration option.  Contact Firebase support directly if you have more questions about it.